# Python Requests. POSTing JSON NameError for boolean

Tags: python, json, docker, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to POST JSON content to an API using Python and requests but I'm getting a `NameError` because my JSON contains a boolean.

I've tried with urllib3 and just requests and both display the same behaviour.

```
"enabled": true,
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

I'm building in docker:

```
FROM python:slim

ADD script.py requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "script.py"]
```

requirements.txt

```
requests==v2.23.0
urllib3==1.25.8
```

script.py

```
#import urllib3
import json

resp = req.post('https://example.com/api/endPoint',
  json={
      "name": "myName",
      "rules": [{
        "type": "foo",
        "enabled": true}]
  })
```

Comment: Try with `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @andreis mentioned try using boolean `True` in below snippet.
In python boolean true is written as `True`

```
#import urllib3
import json

resp = req.post('https://example.com/api/endPoint',
  json={
      "name": "myName",
      "rules": [{
        "type": "foo",
        "enabled": True}]  # from true to True
  })
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=bool#bool

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that and saw that it works. Also, using `payload=json.loads("JSON HERE") .... json=payload` works. I'm raising a bug on GitHub now as this should, IMO, "just work".

Comment: Glad to hear that ! Just a point regarding `json.loads()` when you pass a json document to loads() it uses conversion table to construct python object. In that conversion table you will see it converts `true` to `True`. here is the link https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table